# Yosemite on a windows network keeps crashing apps

Tags: macos, networking, crash, osx-yosemite, finder

I have a Mac Pro Yosemite 10.10.3 connected on a local network with Windows computers/server (it's not connected on the internet) and apps keeps crashing.

Here are few examples:

1. If I use Firefox and try to upload a file on a website, it will open a finder window then crash.
2. If I use Indesign or Photoshop and try to save a file, it will open a finder window and crash (and if I am lucky, it does save the file before crashing).
3. Basically every time I do something with an App in relation to Finder it crashes.

So I guessed that the problem had to do with finder but I tried to remove the com.apple.finder.plist and restart the computer but that did not handle it.

I also tried to disconnect the Mac from the network and restart it but it did not handle it.

Now, I am really running out of ideas. And today I tried to listen to music with my USB headset and iTunes and suddenly the sound stopped playing. I thought my headset were broken so I took another pair and it worked well then few minutes later it stopped again. I unplugged it and plugged it back in, so it started to work again for few minutes and went off again. I've now tried 3 headset and clearly, the problem is not the headset but Mac.

Basically, I am having so much troubles with that Mac Pro, it drives me insane and I keep thinking that it has something to do with Finder.

Sometime when I start searching stuff on the windows server with my Mac, finder crashes and restarts so it must have something to do with Finder.

If anyone finds a solution to that question (other than reinstalling everything) I'll be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like your hardrive is filled and there is no room for the things you mention to run properly. You need to clean up the hard drive. If this does not work then you need to get a decent backup ready and reformat the machine. It may sound draconian but the mac book is such an awesome machine you deserve a fresh start.

Comment: Tks Shoosty and it seems like I will do reformat as I'm getting tired of it. It's definitely not the hard drive since I have over 922Gb free.